# Inverse function of $f(t)=5 +\frac{75}{1 + e^{-((t-50)/10)}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

i need to find the inverse function of
$$
v= f(t)=5 + \frac{75}{1 + e^{-\frac{t-50}{10}}}
$$
so far i have
$$
v - 5 = \frac{75}{1 + e^{-\frac{t-50}{10}}}
$$
$$
(v-5) \left(1 + e^{-\frac{t-50}{10}}\right) = 75
$$
$$
1 + e^{-\frac{t-50}{10}} =\frac{75}{v-5}
$$
$$
e^{-\frac{t-50}{10}} =\frac{75}{v-5}-1
$$
and I'm stuck i need to find t in terms of v.
Is this right or have i made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-(t-50)/10}=\frac{75}{v-5}-1=\frac{80-v}{v-5}$ then taking logs we get
\begin{align}
-\frac{t-5}{10}&=\ln\left(\frac{80-v}{v-5}\right)\\
t-5&=-10\ln\left(\frac{80-v}{v-5}\right)\\
t&=5-10\ln\left(\frac{80-v}{v-5}\right).\\
\end{align}